# 12.10 freezeing. Nothing works except the power button

Tags: 12.10, freeze

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

I am having the same problem Ubuntu 12.10 32bit on a HP G72 laptop. When it freezes you can't do anything. The key board, the mouse, the screen are completely frozen and you can only push the power button to get it to re-start (reboot). I have tried all the keyboard things (like ALT-SysReg R E I S U B) and nothing works because the keyboard is frozen. I don't know what to do. My Windows 7 install (on same laptop) does not freeze. I don't have any pattern of the freeze. It just happens. Then you have no choice but to push the power button. Does anyone have any idea's?  I had 12.04 on this same laptop, and it never froze either.  Are their any log messages that may help me isolate the cause?

Comment: When does it freeze? At bootup or randomly?

Comment: at random, no set pattern

Comment: So the OS works fine most of the time, but freezes at random?

Comment: You might consider [reporting a bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) (though the problem could also arise from the use of a third party driver, or faulty hardware).

Comment: OK I give up.  I tried to explain that I have tried everything in the article "What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?" and nothing works.  So i now give up.  Thanks.